# Orderby em um array

Tags: array, wordpress

Amigos, estou tentando editar um `array`, para que o mesmo me apresente as informações em ordem ascendente ou decrescente.

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
$Recent_Page = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'imic_home_recent_property_no', true);
query_posts(array('post_type'=>'property', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'orderby'=>'ID', 'order'=>'ASC','posts_per_page', =>$Recent_Page));
```

Nada acontece. o que posso estar errando?

Answer (score 2):

Conforme [exemplo do codex do wordpress sobre query_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts), segue abaixo:

```
$Recent_Page = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'imic_home_recent_property_no', true);

$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'property',
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'orderby'=>'ID',
    'order'    => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' =>$Recent_Page
);
query_posts($args);
```